# Why does IE choke on ({function:1}[typeof somefunc])?

Tags: javascript

Ok, I've been doing some research and starting using this convention when testing for object types or more apt, detecting typeof ..

```
 ({function:1}[typeof somefunc])
```

and this works, but alas - I tested in IE, error. So, no longer using it.. :-) ,.. but.

So, I reverted to testing in a standard way, no biggie (typeof somefunc === "function" or $.isFunction(somefunc)). But I am curious "why" it doesn't work in IE.

Also, can someone explain why this "does" work in Firefox, or what i mean to say is that the expression is odd to me, I want to know the internals of WHY It works (even though in selective browsers). I don't understand how its backreferencing the function:1 as a test with the typeof?

Comment: I think you can just do `({"function":1}[typeof somefunc])` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JScript parser in IE8 and earlier is following the old ECMAScript 3.1 (1999) rules for object initializers, which require that if you want to use a reserved word (like `function`) as a property name, it must be in quotes. As of ECMAScript5 (2009), the quotes aren't required anymore because the context is unambiguous. Versions of IE released since the spec was updated (IE9+) do allow you to leave off the quotes.

The difference is that in ECMAscript5, the *PropertyName* in [the object initializer grammar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) is just *IdentifierName*, not *Identifier*. *Identifier* is an *IdentifierName* that isn't a *ReservedWord*. `function` is a valid *IdentifierName*, but not a valid *Identifier* because it is a *ReservedWord*. More: [*Identifier Names* and *Identifiers*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6). But the older spec didn't make that distinction between *IdentifierName* and *Identifier*, and so to use `function` there, you have to put it in quotes. *(Thanks to [chuckj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70261/chuckj) for reminding me that this changed in ECMAScript5.)*

> Also, can someone explain why this "does" work in Firefox, or what i mean to say is that the expression is odd to me...

Yes, it's quite odd and anyone working on code using it is likely to stumble on it. It's a short way of writing `(typeof somefunc=="function")`. Here's what's happening:

1. The expression creates an object with one property, in this case the property name is `function` and the value is `1`.
2. The `typeof somefunc` part is evaluated and returns `"function"` for a JavaScript function, `"object"` for a wide range of objects, `"number"` for a number primitive, `"string"` for a string primitive, etc.
3. That property name is used to look up a property on the object created in Step 1. If the property is found, the overall result of the expression is `1`, a truthy value. If the property is not found, the overall result is `undefined`, a falsey value.

So `({function:1}[typeof somefunc])` tests if `typeof` returns `"function"` for `somefunc`. Similarly you can do `({object:1}[typeof someobj])` to check if `typeof` returns `"object"` for `someobj`, or `({string:1}[typeof somestring])` to check if `typeof` returns `"string"` for `somestring`.

---

Side note: This obscure way of doing the test doesn't perform well ***at all*** compared to the straightforward `(typeof somefunc=="function")`: [Test when true](http://jsperf.com/obscure-typeof-vs-straightforward-typeof) | [Test when false](http://jsperf.com/obscure-typeof-vs-straightforward-typeof-false-test) Unsurprising, given that `typeof x == y` can be highly optimized by a good optimizing engine. So this way of doing the check is harder to read, longer, no easier to type, and usually slower. Hmmm.... :-)

Comment: Thank you for that link! appreciate it. I will read up on it!

Comment: T.J - as another poster mentioned below: Would there be a reason to use this convention over say, a more popular one? typeof somefunc === "function" etc.. over the method I mentioned above? speed? etc.. I am curious why I have seen this convention in some plugins if it's just a preference and nothing gained. Because it is kinda cryptic.

Comment: This is not a JScript bug but the lack of ECMAScript 5 support in browser that predate ECMAScript 5.

Comment: @jamesemanon: In my view, there's no good reason for using this. I don't see any advantages to outweigh the lack of clarity. It's not fewer characters (and if it were, that wouldn't be a good enough reason), and [it's a **lot** slower](http://jsperf.com/obscure-typeof-vs-straightforward-typeof) unless you cache and reuse the object (in which case it's still a **lot** slower on Chrome and Firefox, and only about the same on IE). So: Hard to read, and no solid benefit. Easy case for: Just use the straightforward test.

Comment: The 1999 spec for _PropertyName_ only mentions _Identifier_. _IdentiferName_ used in 5.0 is new to 5.0.

Comment: @chuckj: My mistake, when I double-checked, I clicked the wrong PDF. :-) And in fact, I just tested IE9 (released in 2009, same year as the ECMAScript5 spec), and it works without quotes there. (IE8, pre-ECMAScript5, requires the quotes.) So they adopted that new definition *right away*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for editing the answer to the results of our discussion! You might also want to point out that `typeof somefunc==="function"` is optimized by modern engines to be extremely fast (just an object type check) where `{function: 1}[typeof somefunc]` will never be.

Answer (score 3):

`{function:1}` is an object with exactly one key, `'function'`, mapped to a truthy value, `1`. So, `({function:1}['function'])` is truthy, but (for example) `({function:1}['string'])` is falsy.

Most likely, the reason that IE doesn't support it is that `function` is a reserved word (as you must know), and IE apparently is getting confused by its use in this context. (If so, this is a mistake in IE: surprisingly, the spec actually does allow reserved words to be used in this context.)

Comment: We know *why* it works. The question is why *doesn't it work in IE?*

Comment: @deceze: Not exactly. The original post asked, "can someone explain why this 'does' work in Firefox". It also asked about why it doesn't work in IE, but I focused on explaining why it works to begin with, because it doesn't make sense to explain why it doesn't work if you don't understand why it does. (But either way, I've now updated my answer to answer both questions.)

Comment: @deceze: Op asks: `can someone explain why this "does" work in Firefox` so this answer doesn't deserve the downvote.

Comment: And the title of the question is *Why does IE choke on ({function:1}[typeof somefunc])?*. Both questions are now answered (they weren't initially) and I have already removed the downvote.

Comment: @ruakh The ES3 specification, which is supported by IE 7 and 8 and in IE 9 - 11 in compatibility mode doesn't allow reserved words in this position. ES5, supported by IE 9 - 11, does. This is not a bug in IE but, rather, a change in the spec that was supported after IE 9, the first IE to support ES5.

Comment: @chuckj: Ah, that explains it, thanks! (And I see that the accepted answer has already incorporated that information from your comment to it.)

Answer (score 2):

just put `function` in quotes as `function` is a reserved keyword but `"function"` is just a string literal

```
({"function":1}[typeof somefunc])
```

should work just fine

but then, why won't you simply use:

```
(typeof somefunc == "function")
```

it's shorter and more intuitive

Comment: wow, you are right. I just tested. it does muck on the fact that it wasn't stringed. great eye.!